# Get SUM in related table. If not found get 0 as sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT m.id FROM members m
          LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.user_id = m.id AND
            YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
            MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = o.user_id";
```

I need to get sum of transactions.points, so I do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT m.id, COALESCE(SUM(t.points), 0) AS total_points FROM members m
          LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.user_id = m.id AND
            YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
            MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = o.user_id";
```

But when i execute this, I will get only rows with some transactions (and orders). What I must to do for getting 0 as total_points when no transactions found?

Text description: I want to get sum of points reward (from transactions table) of orders (orders table), where order was created in last month.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query without which you are actually performing `SUM()` on the entire resultset. Not sure on which column but say on `m.id`

```
$sql = "SELECT m.id, COALESCE(SUM(t.points), 0) AS total_points FROM members m
          LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.user_id = m.id AND
            YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
            MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id = o.user_id
          GROUP BY m.id";
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the sum of points per user and use it in the `left join` to get `0` when the user has no transactions.

```
SELECT m.id, COALESCE(t.total_points, 0) AS total_points
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.user_id = m.id AND
/* use this instead of functions which prevent indexes on the date column from being used */
o.date >= date '2016-11-01' AND o.date <= date '2016-11-30' 
LEFT JOIN (select user_id, SUM(points) total_points 
           from transactions group by user_id) t ON t.user_id = o.user_id
```

Comment: try the edited version..there was an alias `t` in the derived table..i removed it.

Comment: Still not works. Solution above works well, but very thanks for you too.